# Hibernate: Object having the data still doesn't save doesn't give any exception

Tags: hibernate, model-associations

Actually i have two databases, i  am fetching the data from one data base i am trying to save the same object(child reference also) into differnt but at database it is not saving, even though it is not giving any exception. Could you please give me any solution for the same.

one observation:
it is saving using the below code:

```
try {
                session=getSession();
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                List<Member> memberList = null;
                List<Proposal> proposalList = null;
                 List<ReductionScheduleMatrix> ReductionScheduleMatrixList = null;
                 for(GroupClass groupClass : groupClasses){
                     GroupClass = new GroupClass();
                     GroupClass.setId(groupClass.getId());
                     GroupClass.setCensus_pk(groupClass.getCensus_pk());
                     GroupClass.setGroupClassNumber(groupClass.getGroupClassNumber());
                     proposalList = new ArrayList<SCProposal>();
                     for(Proposal proposal : groupClass.getProposals()){
                         Proposal sCProposal = new Proposal();
                         Proposal.setId(proposal.getId());
                         StandardLifeBenefit sCStandardLifeBenefit = new StandardLifeBenefit();
                             if(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit()!=null){
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setId(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getId());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setMaximumBenefit(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getMaximumBenefit());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setMinimumBenefit(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getMinimumBenefit());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setFlatBenefitAmount(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getFlatBenefitAmount());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setSalaryMultiplier(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getSalaryMultiplier());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setEligibilityhours(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getEligibilityhours());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setAgeScheduleOPtion(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getAgeScheduleOPtion());
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setGuaranteedIssue(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getGuaranteedIssue());

                                 if(proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getReductionScheduleMatrix()!=null){
                                 ReductionScheduleMatrixList = new ArrayList<SCReductionScheduleMatrix>();
                                 for(ReductionScheduleMatrix redSchMatric : proposal.getStandardLifeBenefit().getReductionScheduleMatrix()){
                                     ReductionScheduleMatrix sCReductionScheduleMatrix = new ReductionScheduleMatrix();
                                     sCReductionScheduleMatrix.setId(redSchMatric.getId());
                                     sCReductionScheduleMatrix.setAge(redSchMatric.getAge());
                                     sCReductionScheduleMatrix.setReductionPercentage(redSchMatric.getReductionPercentage());
                                     ReductionScheduleMatrixList.add(sCReductionScheduleMatrix);

                                 }
                                 sCStandardLifeBenefit.setsCReductionScheduleMatrix(ReductionScheduleMatrixList);
                             }                           
                                 sCProposal.setsCStandardLifeBenefit(sCStandardLifeBenefit);    
                                 }

                         SCADDBenefit scaddBenefit = new SCADDBenefit();
                            if(proposal.getAddBenefit()!=null){
                                scaddBenefit.setId(proposal.getAddBenefit().getId());
                                scaddBenefit.setFlatBenefitAmount(proposal.getAddBenefit().getFlatBenefitAmount());
                                sCProposal.setsCaddBenefit(scaddBenefit);
                            }
                            proposalList.add(sCProposal);
                     }
                    memberList = new ArrayList<SCMember>();
                     for(Member member : groupClass.getMembers()){
                         Member sCMember = new Member();
                         sCMember.setId(member.getId());
                         sCMember.setLifeNumber(member.getLifeNumber());
                         memberList.add(sCMember);
                     }
                     sCGroupClass.setsCMembers(memberList);
                     sCGroupClass.setsCProposals(proposalList);
                     session.saveOrUpdate(sCGroupClass);
                }
                    tx.commit();        
            }
```

from the above code if i change below code

```
 memberList = groupClass.getMembers();
                    /* for(Member member : groupClass.getMembers()){
                         Member sCMember = new Member();
                         sCMember.setId(member.getId());
                         sCMember.setLifeNumber(member.getLifeNumber());
                         memberList.add(sCMember);
                     }*/
```

these Member table is not populating, i have verified while saving the entity, entity has member details also.can you please help on the same.

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you try to save object to the same DB or different? Piece of code ([mcve]) would be nice

Comment: different database, but modeling is same for both the databases, that's why i am using the same entities, please find the above example code